# How to add a Graph placeholder and Table Placeholder in PDF template using Aspose.dll

Tags: pdf, aspose.pdf

How to add a Graph placeholder and Table placeholder in PDF template using Aspose.dll

Please help me in this area.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a graph to a PDF document by using the code below:

```
    // Create Document instance
    Document doc = new Document();

    // Add page to pages collection of PDF file
    Page page = doc.Pages.Add();

    // Create Graph instance
    Aspose.Pdf.Drawing.Graph graph = new Aspose.Pdf.Drawing.Graph(100, 400);

    // Add graph object to paragraphs collection of page instance
    page.Paragraphs.Add(graph);

    // Create Rectangle instance
    Aspose.Pdf.Drawing.Rectangle rect = new Aspose.Pdf.Drawing.Rectangle(100, 100, 200, 120);

    // Specify fill color for Graph object
    rect.GraphInfo.FillColor = Aspose.Pdf.Color.Red;

    // Add rectangle object to shapes collection of Graph object
    graph.Shapes.Add(rect);

    dataDir = dataDir + "CreateFilledRectangle_out.pdf";
    // Save PDF file
    doc.Save(dataDir);
```

And, you can add a table in a PDF document by using the code below:

```
    // Create Document instance
    Aspose.Pdf.Document doc = new Aspose.Pdf.Document();

    // Add page to pages collection of PDF file
    Page page = doc.Pages.Add();

    // Initializes a new instance of the Table
    Aspose.Pdf.Table table = new Aspose.Pdf.Table();

    // Set the table border color as LightGray
    table.Border = new Aspose.Pdf.BorderInfo(Aspose.Pdf.BorderSide.All, .5f, Aspose.Pdf.Color.FromRgb(System.Drawing.Color.LightGray));

    // Set the border for table cells
    table.DefaultCellBorder = new Aspose.Pdf.BorderInfo(Aspose.Pdf.BorderSide.All, .5f, Aspose.Pdf.Color.FromRgb(System.Drawing.Color.LightGray));

    // Create a loop to add 10 rows
    for (int row_count = 1; row_count < 10; row_count++)
    {
        // Add row to table
        Aspose.Pdf.Row row = table.Rows.Add();

        // Add table cells
        row.Cells.Add("Column (" + row_count + ", 1)");
        row.Cells.Add("Column (" + row_count + ", 2)");
        row.Cells.Add("Column (" + row_count + ", 3)");
    }

    // Add table object to first page of document
    doc.Pages[1].Paragraphs.Add(table);

    dataDir = dataDir + "document_with_table_out.pdf";
    // Save updated document containing table object
    doc.Save(dataDir);
```

You may visit following links for further information on these topics.

- [Working with Graphs](https://docs.aspose.com/display/pdfnet/Working+with+Graphs)
- [Working with Tables](https://docs.aspose.com/display/pdfnet/Working+with+Tables)

**P.S:** I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: CAn you please suggest how to bind the data with graph

Comment: Thank yo u very much for your help. Can you also please provide solutiion o n how to create a demo to push a graph from  crystal reports using  Aspose. many thanks in advance.

Comment: Kindly elaborate your requirements while mentioning the steps to achieve the same with Adobe Acrobat, because Aspose.PDF mimics the behavior of Adobe Acrobat.
**P.S:** Please always create separate post for separate  inquiries or you can post over Aspose Forums to ensure quick response.